# Devise omniauth stopped working for some unknown reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have Ruby on Rails application that uses [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and `user` model has `omniauthable` attribute, i.e. users can sign in via social network accounts (application allows google and linkedin).

Sign in via social networks worked until I try to setup email confirmation of registration.
Now any social registration attempt causes `Invalid credentials` error, altough `config.omniauth` rows and environment variables with credentials have not been change.

In production mode social registration still works, and I download old code from server (Development and production environments uses same credentials). But it not helped, and I still can't use socian networks for sign in my application in development mode. I thought browser cache is the reason of this bug, but in others browsers I saw same error message.

My `devise.rb` code:

```
Devise.setup do |config|

    config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
    config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
```

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable,
        :registerable,
        :recoverable,
        :rememberable,
        :trackable,
        :validatable,
        :omniauthable,
        :omniauth_providers => [
            :google_oauth2,
            :linkedin
        ]
```

Does I understand correctly that credentials are social network application id and secret?

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `omniauth-oauth2` gem and most likely appeared after `bundle install` or `bundle update` command.

When I compared gems at development computer and production server, I found that `omniauth-oauth2` gem has different versions. Then I rollback this gem version and application began working.

Thank for help!

Update: issue is already created at [github](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81)

Answer (score 0):

Add the file config/api_keys.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  linkedin:
    api_key: "KEY"
    api_secret: "SECRET"

  development:
    <<: *defaults

  production:
    linkedin:
      api_key: "KEY2"
      api_secret: "SECRET2"
```

Then in my devise.rb file I do:

```
API_KEYS = YAML::load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/api_keys.yml")[Rails.env]
config.omniauth :linkedin , API_KEYS['linkedin']['api_key'], API_KEYS['linkedin']['api_secret']
```

Comment: It didn't help. As I understand, your answer decides problem with keys and secrets receiving. But when I debugged application, ```ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY']``` and ```API_KEYS['linkedin']['api_key']``` returned same values. Both production and development evnironments uses same keys and secrets, and I sure that values are correct because of production server works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have removed your devise secret key in development.

Use `rake secret` to generate one.

Comment: No, it didn't help :(